# How to get non matched records value with MongoDb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am new to Mongo Db and would appreciate some help with this query.I wrote mongodb aggregation one my field "lampStatus": 'OFF' is 30 records are there and "lampStatus": 'ON' is no records are there i got out put  {"OFF" : 30} i have not getting {"ON" : 0} value please any one suggest me.

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match:{"type" : "L"}},
  { "$facet": {
    "ON": [
      { "$match" : {"lampStatus":'ON'}},
      { "$count": "ON" }
    ],
    "OFF": [
      { "$match" : {"lampStatus": 'OFF'}},
      { "$count": "OFF" }
    ]
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "ON": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$ON.ON", 0] },
    "OFF": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$OFF.OFF", 0] }
  }},

])
```

output:{
    "OFF" : 30
}

```
expected ouput:{
  "OFF" : 30,
  "ON":0
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [**`$ifNull`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) with the [**`$project`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage something like this

```
{ "$project": {
  "ON": { "$ifNull": [{ "$arrayElemAt": ["$ON.ON", 0] }, 0 ] },
  "OFF": { "$ifNull": [{ "$arrayElemAt": ["$OFF.OFF", 0] }, 0 ] }
}}
```

You will get

```
[{
  "OFF": 30,
  "ON": 0
}]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Anthony. This solved my problem. Greatly appreciate the help @ Anthony Winzlet

Comment: hi  Anthony Winzlet any possible this type of json format output {
    "_id" : "ON",
    "count" : 0.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "OFF",
    "count" : 30.0
} @ Anthony Winzlet